# chain functions: how to cancel the result of the first function?

Tags: javascript

I created a constructor function `_ ()` and wrote several methods in the prototype, the "enumeration" method, overrides the classes or the id HTML elements.

There is a method which need to refer to a specific element of the `NodeList` (for example `itElement(2)`).  I use chain functions `(_ ('.test'). item (2))`. 
Using the `addMiClass` method, I want to add my class to exactly element (2), but the class has added to all elements `_ ('.test')`.

How to cancel the result of the first function `(_ ('test'))`?

```js
'use strict';

function _(arg) {

  if (!(this instanceof _)) {
    return new _(arg);
  }

  var self = this;
  //we can transmit a string
  if (typeof arg === "string") {
    this.elements = arg.split(',');
    this.element = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
      this.element.push(document.querySelectorAll(this.elements[i]));
    }
  }
  //if transmit object
  if (typeof arg === "object") {

    this.element = [];

    for (var i in arg) {
      //  var index = Object.keys(arg).indexOf(i);//for gettinf index
      this.element.push(document.querySelectorAll(arg[i]));
    }
  }
}

_.prototype = {

  //method for bust elements
  enumeration: function(elements, callback) {

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

      [].forEach.call(elements[i], callback);

    }
    return this;
  },
  //method for adding class
  addMyClass: function(nameClass) {

    this.enumeration(this.element, function(el) {
      // do whatever
      el.classList.add(nameClass);
    });

    return this;
  },

  //for specific elements
  itElement: function(element) {
    element -= 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++) {

      [].forEach.call(this.element[i], function(el, i) {

        if (i === element) {
          return el;
        }

      });
    }

    return this;
  }

}

//////////////////use my object
_('.first').itElement(2).addMyClass('test');
```

```html
<div class="first">ff</div>
<div class="first">ff</div>
<div class="first">ff</div>
<div class="second">ff2</div>
<div class="third">ff3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not `return this`, you have to return a new instance that wraps exactly the elements that you want. (Btw, trying to `return` from a `forEach` callback is futile).

Comment: thanks! I understood where I did not do it correctly